# How to change the logon account of a service (available in services.msc) in windows and start the service using powershell

Tags: powershell, login

I'm trying to create a script that should change the logon account and start the service with the new account credentials added.

I have tried to write the following script and when I run the script the logon account details have changed, however it is not starting the service.

```
$newUsername = "domain\Administrator"
$newPassword = "*****"
Stop-Service -Name "vstsagent.azure"
$serviceName = "vstsagent.azure"
$serviceBinaryPath = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $serviceName }).PathName
$serviceBinaryPath = $serviceBinaryPath -replace '"',''
sc.exe config "$serviceName" obj= "$newUsername" password= "$newPassword"
Start-Service -Name "vstsagent.azure"
```

I'm getting following error:

> Cannot start the service on computer '.'

Is there anything that is missing ?Any assistance is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It's simpler to change the account and password by using the PowerShell
[Win32_Service class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service).

Example code :

```
$service = gwmi win32_service -computer [computername] -filter "name='whatever'"
$service.change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,".\MyAccount","P@ssw0rd"). 
$service.StopService()
while ($service.Started) {
    sleep 2
    $service = gwmi win32_service -computer [computername] -filter "name='whatever'"
}
$service.StartService()
```

You need to prefix the account name with the domain name or "."
for it to work.

Source :
[Powershell script to change service account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313622/powershell-script-to-change-service-account).
See the answers in this post for more examples.